# How can I convert a LightGBM model to ONXX?

Tags: python, asp.net, machine-learning, scikit-learn, onnx

I'm trying to save my model so it can be used in a ASP.NET program, and I think that ONNX is a good way to do so. The problem is that even after checking the docs and googling it all day, I still get the same error `raise ValueError('Initial types are required. See usage of ' ValueError: Initial types are required. See usage of convert(...) in skl2onnx.convert for details`. I have no idea what's going on and any help is greatly appreciated!

**My Code**

```
import onnxmltools
from skl2onnx import convert
import lightgbm as lgb
import pandas as pd

parameters = {
    'boosting': 'gbdt',
    'feature_fraction': 0.5,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.5,
    'bagging_freq': 20,
    'num_boost_round': 10000,
    'verbose': -1 #maybe?
}


model_lgbm = lgb.train(parameters, train_data, valid_sets = test_data, early_stopping_rounds = 200);

onnx_model = convert.convert_sklearn(model_lgbm, ???);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this doc](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-docker/blob/master/onnx-ecosystem/converter_scripts/lightgbm_onnx.ipynb) will help you.

You have to use :
onnxmltools.convert_lightgbm
and not
convert.convert_sklearn

Comment: That fixed the error but I the problem I now have is with this line `onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert_lightgbm(lgb_model, initial_types=[(variable_name, data_type), (variable_name, data_type)])`. Is there a way to do this automatically as I have a LOT of columns in my dataset or is it referring to something else?

Comment: According to [this document](http://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/introduction.html?highlight=initial_types#convert-sklearn-to-onnx-initial-types), even if there are many columns, the initial_type is maybe like `initial_type=[('X', FloatTensorType([None, train_data.shape[1]]))]`, since the second dimension is the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

1. As the other answer mentions: You have to use : onnxmltools.convert_lightgbm and not convert.convert_sklearn
2. The error would also be caused since you have not defined the initial_types. The inital_types are in the [Docs](http://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/api_summary.html) described as follows:

Example of initial_types: Assume that the specified scikit-learn model takes a heterogeneous list as its input. If the first 5 elements are floats and the last 10 elements are integers, we need to specify initial types as below. The [None] in [None, 5] indicates the batch size here is unknown.

```
from skl2onnx.common.data_types import FloatTensorType, Int64TensorType
initial_type = [('float_input', FloatTensorType([None, 5])),
                ('int64_input', Int64TensorType([None, 10]))]
```